# multiple validation for single field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have 3 fields `'account_name','billable_option' and 'billable_option_yes'`
`'billable_option'` is required if `'billable_option_yes'` is not filled and `'billable_option_yes'` is required if `'billable_option'` is not filled

and I want to check both field is not required if 'account_name' value is 0
I want to combine the validation required_unless:account_name,0

```
if($account!=0){ } not working



$account=$request->account_name;        
     if($account!=0){ //not working
                $this->validate($request,[
                'billable_option' => 'required_without:billable_option_yes',
                'billable_option_yes' =>'required_without:billable_option',
                ],$messages); 
    }
   $messages=[
            'billable_option.required_without'=>'The Billable is Required',
            'billable_option_yes.required_without'=>'The Billable optoion is Required',
       ];
      $this->validate($request,[
        ...
       'billable'=>'required_unless:account_name,0', //fourth field working fine
        ..
      ],$messages);
```

Comment: two things first if you want to check this type of validation some where else then make your own validation else check this manually (in if else case)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the [Require if](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required-if) validation rule from the docs.

> **required_if:anotherfield,value,...**
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to any value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked comparison used in if condition,

If your `account_name` field is string, then you can't compare like this:

```
if($account != 0)
{
    ....
}
```

This will compare string `$account` with integer 0 so that condition will never true. So, you have to change like,

```
if($account != '0')
{
    ....
}
```

Now, Another thing is you want no validation check up for `billable_option` and `billable_option_yes` if account is 0.

So, you can write validation method inside single if condition and no need to add further validation code after the end of if condition.

```
if($account != '0'){     // if $account is string variable
        $this->validate($request,[
            'billable_option' => 'required_without:billable_option_yes',
            'billable_option_yes' =>'required_without:billable_option',
            ],
        $messages = [
            'billable_option.required_without'=>'The Billable is Required',
            'billable_option_yes.required_without'=>'The Billable option is Required',
        ]); 
}
```

Hope you understand.